# Eclipse Compilation error - Type mismatch;found:Unit required Int in Scala

Tags: scala

I am a newbie in scala and started out writing some code in Eclipse. I have three methods out of which second one complains with error mentioned in subject

```
  def add(b:Byte):Unit = sum+=b
  def add1(b:Byte):Int = sum+=b
  def add2(b:Byte):Int = sum
```

Why is the third method not complaining and while second method does ? The code I wanted to write was something like "add b to sum an return the new sum" as concisely as possible. So even after declaring a return type of Int in second method, why doesn't scala understand an implicit return in the second method while it does the same for third method ?

Comment: If you want to return sum: `def add1(b:Byte):Int ={ sum+=b; sum }`

Comment: @insaan-e - Thanks for that, I understood the point!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `+=` is `Unit`. So `add1` implicitly returns what `+=` returns and that's `Unit`.